# SpringBoot - Unable to start embedded container

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My SpringBootLoginController class throw this error( unable to start embedded container) which is shown below when i have started the springboot application.It is a hello world kind spring boot application example.

```
   .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloSpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>HelloSpringBoot</name>
    <description>HelloSpringBoot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My Controller :

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class SpringBootLoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootLoginController.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Annotating with the **@SpringBootApplication** resolves this issue.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringBootLoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootLoginController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Alternatively , by Adding the **@EnableAutoConfiguration , @ComponentScan and @Configuration** also  resolves this issue.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class SpringBootLoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootLoginController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try annotating your `SpringBootLoginController` class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringBootLoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootLoginController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For my case, I was developing a command line project with springboot.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
//my code here
}
```

So I was just using the simple starter.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

But I also got this error, and there was no web related dependency in my pom which was really wired.

And at last I found out that one of my dependency project was using the "javax.servlet.Servlet" in its own pom.

If you check the source code of the springboot, it will check if there is any "javax.servlet.Servlet" in your project when starting the application. And try to start a web "embedded container" when there is any "javax.servlet.Servlet".

That's why I got this error because I was using the "spring-boot-starter" and there was no web container in it.

So the solution is very simple, just tell the springboot that this is not a web project in the "application.properties":

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

Answer (score 4):

I deleted my .m2 repo, changed my version from 1.3.1 to 2.1.3 for the below, did a maven clean, re-build the project and it ran first time (using intellij)

```
parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
</parent>
```

Comment: Hey Mark, This question is more than 2 years old - if you'd like to focus your efforts on new questions, you can use the "Newest" tab to achieve that. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven?tab=Newest) is the link to newest Maven questions.

Comment: Fair point, just added an answer as I had the same problem and fixed it in what looked like a new way. As a newbie, sure I will get the stackoverflow idea soon!

Answer (score 2):

Change the version of the `org.springframework.boot` to 2.1.3 from 1.4.2

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

solved issue

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate your `SpringBootLoginController` class. Read about `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringBootLoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootLoginController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven then build by

```
mvn package
```

instead of IDE build jar.

There are many problems with the IDE built jar in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Till now i haven't figured out the issue, but I deleted my .m2 repo, gave the install build and it all worked liked charm

Answer (score -4):

you have a problem on your dependencies. Add this

```
<dependency>
<groupId><groupId></groupId>
<artifactId><some dependency></artifactId>
<version><version></version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```