# How can I start a Main-Class in Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to execute a very simple example which explains the IoC-concept in Spring-Boot.

For that I have create a Bean which gets @Autowired to a main-class, which has a method which does something with the bean.

The bean:

[image]

The main:

```
@Component
public class MyMain {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean bean1;

    public void usingTheBean()
    {
        bean1.setName("Thats my first bean!");
        bean1.setAttribute("And thats just an attribute");

        System.out.println(bean1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //MyMain main = new MyMain();
        //main.usingTheBean();
    }
}
```

My SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        MyMain main = new MyMain();
        main.usingTheBean();
    }
}
```

How can I start the Main-class? with out getting the

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

for the @Autowired Bean "MyBean" in the main?

I know that the reason for the NullPointer-Exception is that I created the Main-class with the "new" keyword.

But the question focuses more on the question "How can I start a main-class with spring-boot"

Comment: why can't you make your MyMain class as spring boot starter class .

Comment: How can I then call the "usingTheBean"-Method?

Comment: You can just check my answer in this post on how to create a basic spring boot application : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447798/springboot-unable-to-start-embedded-container

Comment: @VNT this example uses the RestController-Annotation. Which means, that we want to accomplish slightly different things.
But still thanks for the link, I did help me !

Comment: Incidentally this is why I always recomend constructor based dependancy injection rather than individually annotating each member, it makes it really clear when spring is or isn't going to dependancy inject. If you call the constructor yourself you need to provide the dependancys

Comment: So you mean I should create attributes in that class and assign the in-the-constructor-@Autowired instances to it in the constructor?

Comment: @RichardTingle Dependency Injection is written with 3 e's. No offense! :P

Comment: @watchme Exactly, that's the way I do it whenever possible (you can't do it inside junit unit tests sadly). Makes it easier to reason about

Comment: But isn't that a critical thing when it doesn't work in JUnit?
I mean, I have never used JUnit, but I have heard that it's often used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you do not want to use the context directly to create a bean yourself. You should just let the context initialize and then just use the autowired beans. Most likely, the way you approach this problem is very different from the Spring-way of achieving it.

You should have a look at the following examples:

- using the CommandLineRunner interface (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple/src/main/java/sample/simple/SampleSimpleApplication.java)) or
- using the InitializingBean interface (see [here](http://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring))

Alternatively, you can solve this via configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.setName("...");
    bean.setAttribute("...");
    return bean;
  }
}
```

You can then simply use

```
@Autowired
MyBean myBean;
```

to autowire it.

Yet another alternative would be to inject the values from a config file (e.g. application.properties) if this is possible in your case:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

  @Value("${my.config.value}")
  private String name;

  @Value("${my.config.attribute}")
  private String attribute;

  public MyBean(){

  }
...
```

Having the following entries in your application.properties:

```
my.config.value = Some value content
my.config.attribute = Some attribute content
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between the method where I initialise it by myself through the ApplicationContext and the method where Spring-Initialises it?

Comment: The problem of doing it yourself, is that the rest of the spring context does not know about the values you provide, because the context will be first set up and then your main method will call the setter functions after the context was already set up. So potentially, if other beans of your context depend on your values, they are not going to see them, because you set the values after everything has already been built by the spring context.

Comment: Can I chat with you? I've got some questions regarding this and you seem to know a bit about that.

Comment: I guess it would be best to simply post more questions here on stackoverflow :-) Glad to have helped.

Comment: Regarding you sentence "... if other beans of your contet depend on your values, they are not going to see them"..... 
I thought I know what you mean but I don't.

I have just checked it and found out that when I create a bean with Autowired and MyBean bean = context.getBean(MyBean.class);

Both will have the same function - so wasn't able to see any difference.

When I change a value of the bean created with the second-method, the bean which got Autowired gets changed too.

To everybody can see the values, even if the bean is created with the second method. Or what did you mean?

Comment: What I recommend you is to read up some online resources on the lifecycle of spring beans (simply google for "spring bean lifecycle"). Then think about the case what happens if you have a bean B that is automatically initialized by Spring and depends on another fully initialized bean A to correctly initialize. Assume A is your MyBean in this case. Good luck :-)